# Save bitmap to file

Tags: android, image, bitmap, save

I have tried to implement undo and redo feature in android fingerpaint app. I have tried to implement using the below code.

Error

```
03-26 20:42:12.020: W/System.err(28056): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-26 20:42:12.020: W/System.err(28056):    at baked.soft.FirstActivity.toJPEGFile(FirstActivity.java:341)
03-26 20:42:12.020: W/System.err(28056):    at baked.soft.FirstActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(FirstActivity.java:314)
```

FirstActivity

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
     switch (item.getItemId()) {
     case R.id.tools:
        ll.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
        return true;
     case R.id.import_pics:
         getPhotos();
         return true;
     case R.id.save:
        toJPEGFile();
     return true;
     case R.id.trash:
         trash();

         return true;
     }
    return false;

}

private void toJPEGFile() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
    try {
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
           finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out); // ERROR 341 LINE
           out.flush();
           out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I don't know where is wrong. please help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your finalBitmap is null for sure....

Comment: finalBitmap is 341 line but I don't know how can be null sorry but I'm begginer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
       finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
```

as you point out is the error line.

`finalBitmap` has not been initialised.

Aka, it is not a bitmap, it is a null value. Make sure you load your bitmap into this variable first.

```
finalBitmap = .... // assign finalBitmap.
finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);  // Then save to file
```

Edit:

reading from your comment, one way to do it would be to do the following, in `onDraw` method:

```
  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
  finalBitmap = bitmap;
```

But again, ive no idea where you are getting bitmap from. Is this another global variable? Maybe you could just change `finalBitmap.compress...` to `bitmap.compress...`

Comment: /***protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  paint.setPathEffect(null);
  
     
  if(bitmap!=null){
   
   canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    for(MyCircle circle:circleList){// draw circles
     
     myCanvas.drawCircle(getCircleMidPointX(circle.firstX, circle.lastX),getCircleMidPointY(circle.firstY, circle.lastY),circle.radius,myPaint);
    }
   
  }****/ here is my bitmap from canvas how can I assign it?

Comment: @user2212477 see edit. Still not sure where your bitmaps are coming from. `bitmap` could also be null. Worth a try, if you have initialised it in your `onCreate` or something.

Comment: can I upload the code dor download to see where is exactly my problem?

Comment: @user2212477 I do not have access to an android phone until tomorrow. But you can send the main java file, and I can quickly read through it. Use http://pastebin.com/ or something.

Comment: http://www.4shared.com/zip/7fhC6VYk/soft.html? here you have CanvasView.java and FirstActivity.java